# GnomeBaker CD/DVD writer no longer lets me burn DVD's or CD's

Tags: 10.04

Is there a way to fix this problem with Gnomebaker CD/DVD Writer? 
When it won't burn, it gives this output:

> PERFORM OPC failed with SK=3h/POWER CALIBRATION AREA ERROR]: Input/output error –

Comment: when you say not working anymore what do you mean? can you add some details of what you have tried and what you are experiencing?

Comment: My Brasero won't burn either "unknow error" with Brasero When it won't burn with Gnomebaker it says this in the output information.--> Executing 'genisoimage -gui -V GnomeBaker data disk -A GnomeBaker -p sarena -iso-level 3 -l -r -hide-rr-moved -J -joliet-long -graft-points --path-list /tmp/GnomeBaker-sarena/gnomebaker-6W2YAW | builtin_dd of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
:-[ PERFORM OPC failed with SK=3h/POWER CALIBRATION AREA ERROR]: Input/output error

Comment: can you edit your question to include the entire error message posted above?

Comment: ok...do you think that is enough information or should I add the whole output message like I did in the response to you?

Comment: you need to add ALL the output information, you should add any updated information to the original question rather than a comment where it can get buried if the comments get too long

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible causes of this error.  Writable disks have an area reserved for calibrating how much power to use for burning (called the OPC area).  The error you are getting means that that drive can't manage to write a test pattern to that area to calibrate itself.  The most common cause of this error is a bad disk, and the second most common cause is a dirty lens in the drive.  Try a different disk from a different section of the package (bad ones tend to show up on top due to higher UV exposure).  If that doesn't work, assuming the drive can still read CDs, go get a cleaning disk and follow its instructions.

If the disk you are using is a rewritable medium (CD-R, DVD+/-R, etc) it sometimes happens (especially with CDs) that the OPC area fills up after multiple sessions with only fast blanking.  Running a full erase can sometimes bring the disk back into a usable state.

Answer (score 0):

Try Brasero Disc Burner. It's the default program in Ubuntu. I have tried to burn my Audio CD and it has nice and simple-to-use interface.

Comment: My Brasero won't burn either. It's "unknown error" with Brasero (thank you very much for the response :-)

Comment: I experienced that Brasero is not invulnerable for this problem. From my `brasero-session.log`: BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): [3 73 03] Medium error. Power calibration area error.

Answer (score 0):

Use k3b. It works fine with 11.10. If you burn Video then use Devede. If you work with ISO then Install AcetoneISO